# c++ expected primary expression before const error, in a simple header file

Tags: c++

In a header file, I want to declare a short function
Rotate(array, degree), which would rotate an array of elements by some degree:

for example, if my array contains {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, and the rotation degree is 2, then the modified array should be {4, 5, 1, 2, 3}.

My code is as follows:

```
#ifndef ROTATE_ARRAY_H
#define ROTATE_ARRAY_H

void Rotate(std::vector<int>& array, const int rotation_degree);

#endif  // ROTATE_ARRAY_H
```

Now this short header file gives "expected primary expression before const"
on the line, where void is declared.

Note that if I remove vector from the function argument list, then

```
void Rotate(const int rotation_degree);
```

compiles successfully (but of course does not work as expected). So I believe, the problem is something to do with the vector.

Please bare in mind that this is a header file, and no code like

```
include<vector>; 
using namespace std;
```

is allowed, as that would violate the style guide.

So the question is: how to get rid of "expected primary expression before const" error?

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Which style guide forbids you from including another header in your header?

Comment: You can use a `#include <vector>` and that header will certainly compile.

Comment: Who said that no code like `#include<vector>;` is allowed? How comes that you use something like `vector` which is undefined at that moment and you expect it to compile without problem???

Comment: You have showed us the header file, but you also need to show us a simple program that gives us this error. Then you likely should show us how you compiled that program, in case you've done some mistakes in that part. (And since this header file is using std::vector, such a program would **need** to `#include <vector>` *before* it includes this header file if you absolutely cannot include <vector> in your header file)

Comment: Why  shouldn't `#include  <vector>` be allowed? That doesn't make sense. It's exactly what you need.

Comment: Well you do `#include <vector>` ***before*** including your header file in the sources, don't you?

Comment: That's a weird style guide - it must be either very old or written by someone very junior.

Answer (score 1):

You need to rewrite (or simply throw out) your ridiculous style guide, and code:

```
#ifndef ROTATE_ARRAY_H
#define ROTATE_ARRAY_H

#include <vector>
void Rotate(std::vector<int>& array, const int rotation_degree);

#endif  // ROTATE_ARRAY_H
```

it's not a question of style, that's how c++ works.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using `std::vector`, you need an `#include <vector>` before you have any code dealing with std::vector.

You have 2 choices here:

Either `#include <vector>` before you include your header file:

```
 #include <vector>
 #include "rotate_array.h"

 int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    std::vector<int> v = ... ;
    rotate(v, 90);
 }
```

Or include it in your headerfile, as any sane coding style would demand:

```
#ifndef ROTATE_ARRAY_H
#define ROTATE_ARRAY_H
#include <vector>
void Rotate(std::vector<int>& array, const int rotation_degree);

#endif  // ROTATE_ARRAY_H
```